# How to define/declare a variable in a class such that its accessible in another files in PHP?

Tags: php, class, static, member, static-members

I need a variable which remains accessible across all the PHP files am using, i.e, I should be able to read it and change its value.

I tried to declare a class in a file with variable x:

In file1.php

```
public class sample{
    public static $curruser = '0';

    public function getValue() {
        return self::$curruser;
    } 

    public function setValue($val){
        self::$curruser = $val;
    }
}
```

Its being set in file2.php by calling `sample::setValue($val)`. This page has a redirect to file3.php

I need to access this variable file3.php:

```
include 'file1.php';
print sample::getValue();
```

This gives me `0` instead of the value I set in file2.php.

Clearly, my understanding of static variables in PHP is a little shaky. Is there a proper way to do set and access the variable across files?

Comment: Have you tried Including the file atop the files you want it included in or passing from file to file via get/post.

Comment: You need to use a storage to save state between separate requests.

Comment: @Zapp: include thing didnt work. And I need to change that variable multiple times. file3.php has submit button which redirects to itself. So I dont think get or post would work.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko You mean SessionState and LocalStorage? I am not aware of the concept. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use session or some sort of caching mechanism if you want data to persist between requests.

Comment: Session wont work since I need to change the value of the variable. Can you pls elaborate a little on the caching mechanism part?

Comment: @xerocool, you can change the value of a session variable.  You can use the $_SESSION array just as you would use the $_POST array or the $_GET array.  $_SESSION['myVariable'] = "newValue";

Answer (score 0):

i recommend defining a constant like this:

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME' ,$value);
```

and access the value like this:

```
echo CONSTANT_NAME;
```

or using static function and static values and static functions like this:

```
public static function setValue($val){
    self::$curruser = $val;
}
public static function getValue() {
    return self::$curruser;
}
```

Comment: I tried using static function. Didn't work. Also, if I use define, can I change the variable's value in file3.php?

Comment: Can't use variable names not beginning with $ in PHP..gives error.